# How to get dependent variable name from glm function outcome in R?

Tags: r

I have r code of GLM created by one of my ex colleague. The code looks like

```
 glm_mod <- glm(formula
           , data
           ,weights=sqrt(units_x+units_y)
           ,family = quasibinomial(link="logit")
```

`Formula` defined the relationship between dependent & independent variable. I found there is an issue in formula. It's using incorrect dependent variable but my client is not ready to accept as the code was developed by one of their high efficient ex employee. They want me to show the dependent variable name from the glm outcome. Can you suggest me how should I get dependent variable name from glm outcome?

Comment: If you already have your model named `glm_mod` you can do `glm_mod$formula` and you can see the name of the variable before `~`.

Answer (score 0):

You should able to see which is the dependent variable from the formula object with just subsetting:

```
formula <- as.formula("y ~ x + b")
formula[[2]]
y
# or 
all.vars(formula)[1]
[1] "y"
```